# Vuejs v-bind:href returns warning

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been struggling to correctly bind an object to an anchor on vue.js (note that this is my first time doing vue.js)

```
<li v-for="object in filterArray" :key="branchurl">
<a v-bind:href="object.url"  v-on:click="function(object)"></a>
</li>
```

this gets me a "Property or method "data" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property."

My vue code is like this

```
 var vm = new Vue({
el:  "#app",
data: {

    array: [
        { url:"#1", phone:"", city: "", zipcode: "", name: "", address: "", time1: "", time2: "" },

    ],

},
computed: {
    filterArray: function() {

        return this.arrray;

    }
}
});
```

I would like some help on which is the correct way of doing this because haven't found something that removes the warning.

Thanks

Comment: you are trying to iterate over a function... iterate over the `array` instead..

as in `<li v-for="arrayItem in array" :key="arrayItem.url"><a v-bind:href="arrayItem.url"  v-on:click="filterArray"></a>
</li>`

Comment: Assuming you've copied and pasted, the problem is that you've misspelled `this.array`. It has two "r"s, not three. (And it is certainly possible to iterate over a computed property.)

Comment: no copy paste, just removed the actual function name with the one here. After some tries and going back to the beggining iit seems that vue likes ' between " for v-bind:href to work

Comment: :key="branchurl",where is your 'branchurl' defining?And, when you use v-for, the value of the key should be unique for the entire loop

Answer (score 0):

After some tries and going back to the beggining it seems that vue likes ` between " for v-bind:href to work

ie

```
<a v-bind:href="`?branch=`+array.url"
```